# Android - Client closes connection an image is sent, before receiving a string back

Tags: python, java, android, sockets, serversocket

I have an android app that opens a socket connection with the server and sends an image to a python server. The server receives that image and is supposed to send a string back to confirm the image has been received. However the socket closes down after I end the Output stream, therefore the server receives the image but the client can't receive a string from the server because the client closed the connection.
Therefore, what I want to do is return a string/text confirming the image has arrived to the user client before the socket closes.

This is my Python server that receives the image as bytes decodes and saves it to a directory then sends a message back:

```
from socket import *
import datetime
import cv2
import PIL.Image as Image
from PIL import ImageFile, Image
import io
import base64
import numpy as np
import pickle
import uuid


date_string = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M")

port = 9999
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('', port))
s.listen(1)

while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    img_dir = '/home/Desktop/frames_saved/'
    img_format = '.png'
    try:
        print("Connected by the ",addr)
        #date_string = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M")
        filename = str(uuid.uuid4())
        with open(img_dir+filename+img_format, 'wb') as file:
            while True:
                data = conn.recv(1024*8)
                if data:
                    print(data)
                    try:
                        file.write(data)
                    except:
                        s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
                        s.bind(('', port))
                        s.listen(1)
                        conn.sendall(("Hello World"))
                        

                    
                else:
                    print("no data")
    
                    break
    finally:
        conn.close()
```

What I am trying to do is receive the encoded string in my android client and print/show a toast.

Android client code:

```
 public class SendImageClient extends AsyncTask<byte[], Void, Void> {


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(byte[]... voids) {
            isSocketOpen = true;
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.0.14",9999);
                OutputStream out=socket.getOutputStream();
                DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(out);
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while (isSocketOpen){
                    Log.d("IMAGETRACK", "Wrote to the socket[1]");
                    dataOutputStream.write(voids[0],0,voids[0].length);
                    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
                        Log.d("IMAGETRACK3", "Wrote to the socket[3]");
                    response.append(line);
                    Message clientmessage = Message.obtain();
                    clientmessage.obj = response.toString();
                    Log.d("[MESSAGE]", String.valueOf(clientmessage));
                    // Tries to receive a message from the server
                    out.close();
                    input.close();
                    if(isSocketOpen == false){
                        Log.d("CLOSED", "CLOSED CONNECTION");
                        socket.close();

                        break;
                    }
                }
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }
    }
```

Additionally I noticed that doing `out.close();` will close the stream socket aswell. Here's the log after an image is sent and received by the server:

```
D/IMAGETRACK: Wrote to the socket[1]
D/IMAGETRACK: Wrote to the socket[1]
W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
W/System.err:     at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:124)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:161)
        at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
        at MyApp.MainActivity$SendImageClient.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:2792)
        at MyApp.MainActivity$SendImageClient.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:2780)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

If I try moving  `out.close();` after the while loop, the client will send an infinite amount of data to the server and when i close the server to end the infinite data being receive, instead of a 70Kb image, i will have a 10MB image or more depending on how log I received the bytes.

From the looks of it, I think I would need to somehow stop the image being sent without closing the server to listen to the image being sent back. How can I do that without closing the socket?

Comment: The client should not close the socket if it wants to receive a return string. It looks as the srrver only saves the received bytes to file when the client closes the socket. You have a lot to change. Reconnecting again is not done.

Comment: The client is no longer closing the socket until the app is closed, I added the string being returned from the server aswell

Comment: `the string is apparently sent, but is not received by the android client ` Which string?

Comment: Are images received correctly?

Comment: Yes they are, I can consecutively send them to the server and visualize them where they were saved in the server. Additionally, the logcat prints as far as D/IMAGETRACK: Wrote to the socket[1]. I just tried moving out.close() under the code that is supposed to receive the string and I got the same results

Comment: `the string is apparently sent, but is not received by the android client` Which string?

Comment: conn.sendall(("Hello World")). Reason why I think it's being sent, it's due to the fact there isn't any apparent error being output

Comment: That is a stange sentence to send. Why dont you send :"We received your file. File length ws 12345 bytes."; THat server co de is very strange as just before you send that hello yoy start to listen. That makes no sense. And you do it all after `exept`. Strange. You still did not tell of files size are equal on client and server.

Comment: The reason why i use an try and except  is if the server crashes or stops for any reason, it restarts again. Also, I moved the send data to the else block, I can see the message arriving, even though I wanted to receive the message after the image was sent. It is sending something like this: D/[MESSAGE]: { when=-21m4s137ms barrier=0 }

Comment: All you tell is not to the pont of sending an image and a string. You are talking about a lot ot other things whhich does not make sense. And you still did not tell if received amount of bytes for an image file is the same as file size of original.

Comment: The Image size in android client is: 72982 before sending it to the socket. In the server after it is saved, it has 71,3 KiB.

Comment: After moving the line that sends the string to the client to the else block in the python server, even though I can print a value of the message object that represents the message received. Only after I shut down the server side script, the log [MESSAGE] appears with the value in my previous comment

Comment: `72982` and  `71,3 KiB` ?? You should give both values in bytes of course. Every byte counts.

Comment: 72982 bytes when converted to kibibytes amounts to 71.27 kibibytes, which rounds up to 71.3 KiB in the OS, the image is being sent and received in the same size. I gave you the information as is.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that socket is closed is simple. I have sample program like this before. You have 2 options to do it. Your architecture for sending and receiving a file is not complete and correct.

One option is that you can define a protocol of sending and receiving by your own, which is not standard. For example, you can define special characters such as `##endoffile##`, and send it after your image, then do not close the socket. Server understands that image is received and there is nothing more. Then in client side call receive method until the end of the socket, but before, you have to send data string back to confirm the image has been received, and client closes the socket when receives this string. Remember to add socket timeout wisely for the prevention of infinite socket waiting.

The second solution is that you can use standard protocols such as `HTTP` or `FTP`, but have to read standards of these protocols such as header and body values, and also send and receive files as `multipart`.